# JPA fetchSize not working for relations (ManyToMany/OneToMany) loaded lazy or eager

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I am currently trying to optimize the performance of a small application which loads a lot of data from the Database.
I use standard JPA with Hibernate and Oracle as Database.

I have a `ServiceClass` with a `getAllData` method which simply executes a named query `loadAllData`. FirstResult and MaxResult can also be set to limit data.

The default value for `fetchSize` from the Oracle JDBC driver is `10`, so I manually set it to 100 via

> q.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", 100)

to improve the performance when processing the ResultSet.

The problem is that the hint only works for the entities which are loaded directly by this query, but not for the relations (`ManyToMany`/`OneToMany`) which are resolved eager or lazy!

ServiceClass:

```
public class ServiceClass {

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Data> getAllData(Integer limit, Integer offset) {
        Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("loadAllData", Data.class);

        if (limit != null && offset != null) {
            q.setFirstResult(offset);
            q.setMaxResults(limit);
        }
        q.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", 100);
        List<Data> result = q.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Data entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DATA")
@NamedQuery(name = "loadAllData", 
    //hints=@QueryHint(name=QueryHints.FETCH_SIZE, value="100"), 
    query = "SELECT d FROM Data d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.dataA ORDER BY d.dataId")

public class Data {

    @Id
    @Column(name="DATA_ID")
    private String dataId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private A dataA;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_ID")
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private Set<B> dataSetB;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "DATA_C", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID") })
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private Set<C> dataSetC;
}
```

The debug output shows that the hint works fine if the `Data` object +  `A` object is loaded:

```
15:55:11.337 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
15:55:11.342 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#1], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.348 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 1
15:55:11.348 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#2], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.349 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 2
15:55:11.349 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#3], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.350 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 3
15:55:11.350 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#4], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.351 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 4
15:55:11.351 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#5], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.351 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 5
15:55:11.351 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#6], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.352 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 6
15:55:11.352 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#7], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.353 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 7
15:55:11.353 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#8], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.354 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 8
15:55:11.354 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#9], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.354 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 9
15:55:11.354 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#10], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.355 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 10
15:55:11.355 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#11], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.356 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 11
15:55:11.356 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#12], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 12
15:55:11.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#13], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 13
15:55:11.357 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#14], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.358 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 14
15:55:11.358 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#15], EntityKey[A#5]
15:55:11.359 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 15
15:55:11.359 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[Data#16], EntityKey[A#5]
```

If I do not set the `fetchSize` hint there is a small gap of ~100ms between processing Result row 9 and 10 (Because default `fetchSize` is 10).

The OneToMany as well as the ManyToMany relationship is resolved later, but the `fetchSize` hint does not work as you can see here:

```
15:55:11.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
15:55:11.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1109]
15:55:11.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 1
15:55:11.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1141]
15:55:11.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 2
15:55:11.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1135]
15:55:11.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 3
15:55:11.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1172]
15:55:11.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 4
15:55:11.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1172]
15:55:11.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 5
15:55:11.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1172]
15:55:11.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 6
15:55:11.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1192]
15:55:11.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 7
15:55:11.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1189]
15:55:11.631 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 8
15:55:11.631 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1181]
15:55:11.631 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 9
15:55:11.631 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1181]
15:55:11.730 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 10
15:55:11.731 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1237]
15:55:11.731 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 11
15:55:11.731 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1237]
15:55:11.732 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 12
15:55:11.732 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1237]
15:55:11.733 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 13
15:55:11.733 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1237]
15:55:11.735 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 14
15:55:11.735 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1237]
15:55:11.736 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 15
15:55:11.736 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[B#1235]
15:55:11.736 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 16
```

You can see that it takes ~100ms between Result row 9 and 10 because of the network latency to the DB. So the default `fetchSize` of 10 is used and not the hint I set on the Query.

I also tried to set the hint in the Named Query directly (commented line) or to set the `fetchType` to `EAGER`, but same effect.

Is this a bug or by design? Does anybody knows how to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

The only solution I got so far is to set the `fetchSize` as property in the `persistence.xml`, but I don't want to specify it as global setting.

> `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="100"/>`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. For ManyToOne. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: No, there were only two options I found: Set it globally (see my Edit section). OR Not using (ManyToMany/OneToMany), but instead load the relational entities manually.